# GIT same repository different branches on different machines

Tags: git

I have created a git repository on a linux server. For a longer part I was working alone and everything was working fine. When a friend joined in, he complained that he can only see master branch. I have checked this on my machine as well where I'm also running ubuntu instance within VMWare, and it is really so. To confuse me even more, I was able to push a new branch from ubuntu machine, that is visible only from inside ubuntu client, but not visible on the client on windows.

So the problem I'm facing is that from the two (in my case logically) separate machines, but against the same repository I'm seeing different branches

I originally pushed branches using Git bash on windows, and if I there I run ***git branch -r*** I get:

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/develop
origin/develop2
origin/master
```

on ubuntu ***git branch -r*** I get

```
origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/develop3
origin/master
```

I can do ***git fetch*** as much as I like, simply things act like that they are working against a separate repo (aside for the shared master branch). It could be that I have miss-configured the git server in some way, or maybe an issue with keys, not sure, need suggestions, thanks

Comment: What is `origin` for each of the repositories? Do you have a third repository somewhere (like GitHub), or are you actually accessing each other’s repositories directly?

Comment: the origin is the bare repository that I have install on a remote server. Than I have cloned, branched, pushed, and didn't notice any issues until another person joined. I'm not using GitHub here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `git branch -r` will only list remote branches that are stored within your local repository. So it does not necessarily mean that those branches exist like that on the remote repository itself. By default, `git fetch` will however fetch all branches from the remote repository and add remote references into your local repository. So you will have all branches that exist on the remote locally as well.

What `git fetch` does not do however is clean up remote branches that were created but removed from the remote repository later. To do that, use `git fetch origin --prune`. This will make Git update your remote branch list for the remote repository.

So if the branches got removed later, you will notice it that way. If this will not get the remote branch list in sync, then it is likely, that your remote repositories are actually not the same. You can use `git remote -v` to get a listing of your remote configuration and double-check if it is the same on both machines.

Comment: hi Poke, via git remote -v I get exactly the same output. I have tried with prune option, but still branches are out of sync. However, you're maybe shooting in the right direction, 'cause at one point in past I did lost remote tracking branches, and pushed the local branches again.

Comment: Okay, that’s really weird. As you seem to have direct access to your bare repository, could you get into that directory and run `git branch -a` within it? That way you will at least get a list of branches that *really* exist on the remote repositry. And from there on, we can further see what’s causing all this.

Comment: Hi Poke, a great tip, and I think that you were right with your first answer as well. When I've checked branches directly on the remote, it was matching what I was seeing in ubuntu client. I've created new (old) branches and pushed and all seems fine now. 

One thing is still a mistery to me, when I was cloning on my windows machine from a remote repo in different local repositories, I was always seeing the non-existing remote branches, that is what made an impression that they surely exist remotely. Strange. Thanks for all the help.